# function pointer parameter with type alias

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters, type-alias

im trying some examples in a book(c++ primer by lippman) and 
im trying to learn about function pointers

this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void useBigger (const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2,
            bool (*func)(const std::string &, const std::string &))
            {
                bool valid = func (s1, s2);
                std::cout << __func__ << " is called "
                          << valid <<std::endl;
            }

bool lengthCompare (const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
if (s1.size() > s2.size())
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int main()
{
useBigger ("hello", "sample", lengthCompare);


return 0;
}
```

this code just runs fine 
but when i try using type alias such as typedef

```
#include <iostream>

typedef bool func (const std::string &, const std::string &); /// or typedef bool (*func)(const std::string &, const std::string);

void useBigger (const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2,
            func)
            {
                bool valid = func (s1, s2);
                std::cout << __func__ << " is called "
                          << valid <<std::endl;
            }

bool lengthCompare (const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
if (s1.size() > s2.size())
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int main()
{
useBigger ("hello", "hiiiii", lengthCompare);


return 0;
}
```

it produces an error something like this:

```
  error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: "this code just runs fine " - um no it doesn't. You never closed the parameter list of your function. You're missing a `)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol `func` is a *type alias*, but you use it as a function. You need to actually declare an argument variable and use it instead of the type, like e.g.

```
void useBigger (const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2,
                func f)
        {
            bool valid = f (s1, s2);
            std::cout << __func__ << " is called "
                      << valid <<std::endl;
        }
```

Comment: so basically func is a user type?

Comment: @KrysselTillada It's an alias for a type, and is used as any other type.

Answer (score 0):

Your type defenition need to correct as follows:

From

```
typedef bool func (const std::string &, const std::string);
```

TO

```
typedef bool func (const std::string &, const std::string&);
```

And in function  useBigger  you have to pass the function type with variable name and need to correct function definition as follows:

```
void useBigger (const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2,
            func f)
            {
                bool valid = f (s1, s2);
                std::cout << __func__ << " is called "
                          << valid <<std::endl;
            }
```